# Cannot connect to AWS RDS instance that is not in VPC

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In our company we use few AWS RDS MySQL instances while few of those aren't in any VPC (we have created those 3 years ago).

I need to connect to such an instance using **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** but when I'm trying to do so I'm getting following error after few seconds:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to host_path.amazonaws.com.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> The network path was not found

If I add the port after the host path like described [there](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html)

I'm getting different error:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to host_path.amazonaws.com,3306.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 18 (System.Data)

The thing is that the link above they are talking about DB instance that is within VPC but our isn't.

Did anyone of you stuck with similar issue earlier and maybe know how to resolve that or at least can point me out to the correct way?

I've Googled a lot regarding this issue but every forum or FAQ says about DB instance within VPC which isn't my case.

In screenshot below [image] 
you can see the connection window within the program, all sensitive data has been painted over.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you cant directly connect from SSMS to a MySQL database.  I think you can setup a "Linked Server" (basically an ODBC driver/datasource, then connect to your localhost, which in turn talks to MySQL).

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

I'm assuming your requirement for SSMS is that you plan to reference data from both SQL Server and MySQL? If so, it should work, but its performance wont be great.